# How to build a specific kernel module?

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, compiling, kernel-modules, cryptography

I installed a kernel source from the official Linux kernel repository (http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.15.tar.bz2) and I recompiled it with some needed options to support the mobility IPv6. When I needed a module to encrypt some data I didn't find it among the rest of the modules already built. The modules that I need are: "echainiv" and "authenc".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first step is to determine what configuration options you need to set in order for the module to build. I use

```
make menuconfig
```

for that; `/` followed by the configuration option you want will tell you where to find it and what its dependencies are. For `ECHAINIV`, you need to enable `CRYPTO` and then enable `ECHAINIV` (as a module since that’s what you’re after — in `make menuconfig`, the entry must show `<M>`, not `<*>`).

To build the module, look for the directory containing the corresponding source code:

```
find . -name echainiv\*
```

The code lives in `crypto`, so

```
make crypto/echainiv.ko
```

(from the top-level directory) will build the module for you.

To install the module, assuming you’re running the target kernel, run

```
sudo mkdir -p /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/crypto
sudo cp -i crypto/echainiv.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/crypto
```